# Find all children of a Person along with their Spouse using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like this:

[image: Graph data showing parent-child-parent relation]

Where **John** is married to **Jane** and has a child **Marry**. Also, John has another child named **Mark** whose mother is unknown.

The below cypher returns only one record matching John & Jane.

```
match p=(:Person {name: "John")-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(c:Person) 
return [s in nodes(p) | s.name]


╒══════════════════════════╕
│"[s in nodes(p) | s.name]"│
╞══════════════════════════╡
│["John","Marry","Jane"]   │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

What should be the cypher that gives me the following result?

```
╒══════════════════════════╕
│"[s in nodes(p) | s.name]"│
╞══════════════════════════╡
│["John","Marry","Jane"]   │
╞══════════════════════════╡
│["John","Mark",""]        │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Cypher [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/) statement. It should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the directions. I looked into OPTIONAL MATCH earlier, but your answer re-assured me to find a solution using it. 

For others who might have the same question, below is the cypher I built:

MATCH (person:Person {name: "John"})-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
OPTIONAL MATCH (child)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(parent)
RETURN child, parent